# GamesClient.connect ANR stack trace -- any ideas?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

We have had occasional reports from customers of app launch hangs since integrating Google Play Services. It has been hard to reproduce but we did capture an ANR, any ideas from this? The google_play_services we are using has BUILD_TIMESTAMP = "18 Sep 2013 12:36"

```
Device
JPN:REGZA Tablet AT500 Other countries:TOSHIBA AT300 (tostab11BA)
crane-a732
nuclear-evb
S18

----- pid 12172 at 2013-10-06 12:43:46 -----
Cmd line: com.lootworks.swords

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=1)
"main" prio=5 tid=1 SUSPENDED
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x409f2460 self=0x1d177f0
| sysTid=12172 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1074766984
| schedstat=( 2160359485 1717906811 2458 ) utm=183 stm=33 core=0
at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.<init>(AbstractStringBuilder.java:~83)
at java.lang.StringBuilder.<init>(StringBuilder.java:67)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ObjectIdentifier.toString(ObjectIdentifier.java:137)
at org.apache.harmony.security.x509.AlgorithmIdentifier$1.getDecodedObject(AlgorithmIdentifier.java:150)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:45)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.BerInputStream.readSequence(BerInputStream.java:554)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.DerInputStream.readSequence(DerInputStream.java:105)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Sequence.decode(ASN1Sequence.java:40)
at org.apache.harmony.security.asn1.ASN1Type.decode(ASN1Type.java:91)
at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.<init>(X509CertImpl.java:102)
at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl.getCertificate(X509CertFactoryImpl.java:656)
at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertFactoryImpl.engineGenerateCertificate(X509CertFactoryImpl.java:109)
at java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.generateCertificate(CertificateFactory.java:195)
at com.google.android.gms.common.e.a((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.common.e.x((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.cz.connect((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.w.connect((null):-1)
at com.google.android.gms.games.c.connect((null):-1)
at rp.Cv(SourceFile:556)
at rp.Cu(SourceFile:550)
at rp.Cs(SourceFile:501)
at rp.b(SourceFile:326)
at com.lootworks.swords.activity.SwMap3D.onStart(SourceFile:2296)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1133)
at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:4502)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1929)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I also have crash reports from such device (nuclear-evb, Android 4.0.3 - 4.0.4) in the Developer Console, and this is the only device that is having it. In my case it's java.lang.OutOfMemoryError when creating Bitmap. I still cannot understand why it happens. Did you manage to resolve your exception?

Comment: Our bug is resolved; it seems to have been due to a bug in Google's code that assumed it was running on UI thread. If you are getting OutOfMemoryError creating a BitMap you may be hitting an unrelated issue I have dealt with also, BitMap allocation will fail in some specific devices even when there appears to be sufficient memory left, perhaps due to fragmentation of the available memory for GPU accelerated bitmap manipulation. I think there are some stackoverflow posts about that